# CS50 Luhn's Algorithm in C

Tags: c, cs50, luhn

I'm new to C and I'm doing CS50. I can't get my code to work. I'm almost positive the for statement is correct. The sum given by the for statement is correct.

I think it's something to do with the `(floor(ccNumber / pow(10,13) == 34)` in the if statements.

Explanation of Luhn's Algorithm: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/1/credit/

Sample credit card numbers for testing: https://www.freeformatter.com/credit-card-number-generator-validator.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

void credit(long ccNumber);

int main(void)
{
    long ccNumber = 0;
    credit(ccNumber);
}

void credit(long ccNumber)
{

    do

    {
        ccNumber = get_long("Enter a credit card number: ");
    }

    while (ccNumber < 0);

    {
        int sum = 0;
        long ccNumberFormat = ccNumber;
        int nDigits = floor(log10(ccNumberFormat)) + 1;
        int parity = nDigits % 2; // if parity % 2 == 0 then even number of digits, otherwise odd number of digits


        for (int i = nDigits; i >= 0; i--) {
            int digit = ccNumberFormat % 10;

            if (i % 2 != parity) { // even number credit card digits will be multiplied by 2 every even number (starting from 0)
                digit = digit * 2;
                // printf("%d\n", sum);
            }
            if (digit > 9) {
                digit = digit - 9;
            }

            sum = sum + digit;
            ccNumberFormat /= 10;
            printf("%d\n", sum);
        }

        if (sum % 10 == 0 && nDigits == 15 && (floor(ccNumber / pow(10,13) == 34) || (floor(ccNumber / pow(10,13) == 37))))
        {
            printf("%s\n", "AMEX");
        }
        else if (sum % 10 == 0 && (nDigits == 13 || nDigits == 16) && (floor(ccNumber / pow(10,12) == 4) || floor(ccNumber / pow(10,15) == 4)))
        {
            printf("%s\n", "VISA");
        }
        else if (sum % 10 == 0 && nDigits == 16 && ((floor(ccNumber / pow(10,14) >= 51) || (floor(ccNumber / pow(10,14) <= 55)))))
        {
            printf("%s\n", "MASTERCARD");
        }
    }
}
```

Pseudocode I more or less followed on Wikipedia::

```
function checkLuhn(string purportedCC) {
    int sum := integer(purportedCC[length(purportedCC)-1])
    int nDigits := length(purportedCC)
    int parity := nDigits modulus 2
    for i from 0 to nDigits - 2 {
        int digit := integer(purportedCC[i])
        if i modulus 2 = parity
            digit := digit × 2
        if digit > 9
            digit := digit - 9
        sum := sum + digit
    }
    return (sum modulus 10) = 0
}
```

Comment: (a) Always provide a [mre] when asking for debugging help. That includes sample input that reproduces the problem. (b) “I can't get my code to work” is not a proper problem statement. State what output or other behavior your program shows, state what output or other behavior you desire instead, and, if needed, explain the difference. (c) Stop using `pow` for integer arithmetic. Some `pow` implementations return inaccurate results. (d) Treat credit card numbers as strings of digits, not mathematical integers. It is easier to work with them that way. Get a string, not a long.

Comment: a credit card number is a big number, are you sure `long` is enough rather than `long long` ? Also in  `floor(ccNumber / pow(10,13) == 34)` are you sure you put the ')' at the right place ? probably you wanted `(floor(ccNumber / pow(10,13)) == 34)` and of course same for the other cases, but warning when doing floating point computation ...

Comment: @EricPostpischil (a&b) I added some inputs and stated the output I got. (c)What do I use beside ```pow```? I think ^ doesn't work.

(d) I'm trying to apply what we learned so far in the lesson, which is to use % to get the digits. So no arrays, numbers as strings, etc.

Comment: This problem [has already been address dozens of times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+Luhn%27s+Algorithm).   A high percentage of the students who run into problems, slam into the size of int issue.  In your case, you have that, and why are you using floats in Luhn's algorithm?   Please read the [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: You know, I am starting to think that this particular exercise was explicitly designed to show students, how a simple algorithm implementation; can be spoiled by the use of inappropriately sized integer values.  Most of the detritus, seems to be driven by inappropriate workarounds when things don't work, or when the student feels compelled to obfuscate the code just enough that it doesn't appear to have been copied.

Comment: What am I supposed to use if not float? https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/1/credit/ says to use get_long. I'm just trying to use what is taught in the lessons so far. I spent 10 hours on this problem and only when I couldn't figure out the answer that I post here.

Comment: According to their docs `get_long` return type is long.   What is `sizeof(long)` on your system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A credit card number is a big number, are you sure `long` is enough and you do not need `long long`

Out of that in your expressions like `floor(ccNumber / pow(10,13) == 34)` the ')' is wrongly placed and you wanted `floor(ccNumber / pow(10,13)) == 34` and of course the same for others :

```
    if (sum % 10 == 0 && nDigits == 15 && ((floor(ccNumber / pow(10,13)) == 34) || (floor(ccNumber / pow(10,13)) == 37)))
    {
        printf("%s\n", "AMEX");
    }
    else if (sum % 10 == 0 && (nDigits == 13 || nDigits == 16) &&((floor(ccNumber / pow(10,12)) == 4) || (floor(ccNumber / pow(10,15)) == 4)))
    {
        printf("%s\n", "VISA");
    }
    else if (sum % 10 == 0 && nDigits == 16 && ((floor(ccNumber / pow(10,14)) >= 51) || (floor(ccNumber / pow(10,14)) <= 55)))
    {
        printf("%s\n", "MASTERCARD");
    }
```

but in

```
    else if (sum % 10 == 0 && (nDigits == 13 || nDigits == 16) &&((floor(ccNumber / pow(10,12)) == 4) || (floor(ccNumber / pow(10,15)) == 4)))
```

you take the risk to have a bad result, you need to check `(floor(ccNumber / pow(10,12)) == 4)` only if `nDigits == 13` and `(floor(ccNumber / pow(10,15)) == 4)` only if `nDigits == 16` and you can simplify to have :

```
    else if (sum % 10 == 0 && (nDigits == 13 || nDigits == 16) &&(floor(ccNumber / pow(10,nDigits-1)) == 4))
```

So finally :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void credit(long long ccNumber);

int main(void)
{
  long long cc[] = { 4532057997187363ll, // visa
                     4485661945778178ll, // visa
                     2720995573736457ll, // MasterCard
                     2720998284576493ll, // MasterCard
                     375137447049450ll, // amex
                     378572901284556ll, // amex
  };

 for (int i = 0; i != sizeof(cc)/sizeof(*cc); ++i)
    credit(cc[i]);
  
  return 0;
}

void credit(long long ccNumber)
{
  int sum = 0;
  long long ccNumberFormat = ccNumber;
  int nDigits = floor(log10(ccNumberFormat)) + 1;
  int parity = nDigits % 2; // if parity % 2 == 0 then even number of digits, otherwise odd number of digits
  
  
  for (int i = nDigits; i >= 0; i--) {
    int digit = ccNumberFormat % 10;
    
    if (i % 2 != parity) { // even number credit card digits will be multiplied by 2 every even number (starting from 0)
      digit = digit * 2;
      // printf("%d\n", sum);
    }
    if (digit > 9) {
      digit = digit - 9;
    }
    
    sum = sum + digit;
    ccNumberFormat /= 10;
    //printf("%d\n", sum);
  }
  
  if (sum % 10 == 0 && nDigits == 15 && ((floor(ccNumber / pow(10,13)) == 34) || (floor(ccNumber / pow(10,13)) == 37))) {
      printf("%lld %s\n", ccNumber, "AMEX");
    }
  else if (sum % 10 == 0 && (nDigits == 13 || nDigits == 16) &&(floor(ccNumber / pow(10,nDigits-1)) == 4)) {
    printf("%lld %s\n", ccNumber, "VISA");
  }
  else if (sum % 10 == 0 && nDigits == 16 && ((floor(ccNumber / pow(10,14)) >= 51) || (floor(ccNumber / pow(10,14)) <= 55))) {
    printf("%lld %s\n", ccNumber, "MASTERCARD");
  }

}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall f.c -lm
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
4532057997187363 VISA
4485661945778178 VISA
2720995573736457 MASTERCARD
2720998284576493 MASTERCARD
375137447049450 AMEX
378572901284556 AMEX
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

note also to do floating point computation is a risk, you can do all only using `long long`

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
int main(void)
{
    long ccNumber = 0;
    credit(ccNumber);
}

void credit(long ccNumber)
{
    do
    {
        ccNumber = get_long("Enter a credit card number: ");
    }
```

The call to `credit()` is passing the contents of the variable: `ccnumber` rather than a pointer to `ccnumber`.  So the called function: `credit()` can never change that value in `main()`.

Suggest:

```
int main(void)
{
    long ccNumber = 0;
    credit( &ccNumber );
}

void credit(long * ccNumber)
{
    do
    {
        *ccNumber = get_long("Enter a credit card number: ");
    }
```

In general, should never compare a floating point value with an integer value for equality,  So the following kind of expression is very unreliable:

```
(floor(ccNumber / pow(10,13) == 34)
```

also, such an expression is actually just comparing two digits of the `ccnumber` to 34.   MUCH better to have read the credit card number as a string then comparing the two digits to `ccnumber[ first digit position ] == 3 && ccnumber[ second digit position ] == 4`.   Similar considerations exist for all the other expressions that are using `pow()`

Therefore, suggest getting the credit card number via:

```
string ccnumber = get_string( "enter credit card number" );
```

the result will be a pointer to the string containing the credit card number.  each of the 'interesting' digits can then be accessed as an index (starting with 0) into the credit card number

however, if you really do not want to use a char array, you could replace expressions like;

```
(floor(ccNumber / pow(10,13) == 34)
```

with:

```
(ccNumber / 10000000000000 == 34)
```

Comment: I understand converting the number to string now. They did not introduce it in cs50 yet so I'm trying to use strategies taught up to that point. I also wasn't exactly sure if Python syntax like ```str[0]``` to get the position worked in C.

Comment: in today's internet, all the available statements from `cs50` are very well explained (and demonstrated) .  For instance `get_string()` is fully documented at: [get_string](https://man.cs50.io/3/get_string) and: [all cs50 functions](https://man.cs50.io/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

// Luhn's Algorithm

int main(void) 
{
    long cardNumber = get_long("Please, enter your card number: ");
    int sum1 = 0, num = 0, remainder = 0, sum2 = 0;
    long temp = cardNumber;
    
    while (temp > 0) 
    {
        num = ((temp / 10) % 10) * 2; // Multiplying every other digit by 2, starting with the number’s second-to-last digit
        while (num > 0) 
        {
            remainder = num % 10;
            sum1 += remainder; // Adding those products’ digits together
            num /= 10;
        }
        temp /= 100;
    }
    
    // So as to restore the initial values of remainder and temp for the use in next loop
    remainder = 0;
    temp = cardNumber;
    
    while (temp > 0) 
    {
        remainder = temp % 10;
        sum2 += remainder; // Sum of the digits that weren’t multiplied by 2
        temp /= 100;
    }
    
    ((sum1 + sum2) % 10) == 0 ? printf("Valid\n") : printf("Invalid\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain how your code works and what you changed.

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on concepts explained in week 1

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
long long cardNum;
do
{
    cardNum = get_long_long("Enter Card number: ");
}
while (cardNum < 1);
long long tempCC;
int remNum, sum = 0, sum1 = 0, counter = 1, currentNum, total;
tempCC = cardNum;
do
{
    currentNum = tempCC % 10;
    if (counter % 2 == 0)
    {
        currentNum = currentNum * 2;
        if (currentNum > 9)
        {
            currentNum = currentNum - 9;
        }
        sum += currentNum;
    }
    else
    {
        sum1 += currentNum;
    }
    counter++;
    tempCC = tempCC / 10;
}
while (tempCC > 0);
total = sum + sum1;
if (total % 10 == 0)
{
    tempCC = cardNum;
    do
    {
        tempCC = tempCC / 10;
    }
    while (tempCC < 10 || tempCC > 100);

    if (((counter - 1) == 15) && (tempCC == 34 || tempCC == 37))
    {
        printf("AMEX\n");
    }
    else if (((counter - 1) == 16) && (tempCC >= 51 && tempCC <= 55))
    {
        printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    }
    else if ((((counter - 1) == 13) || ((counter - 1) == 16)) && (tempCC / 10 == 4))
    {
        printf("VISA\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }
 }
 else
 {
    printf("INVALID\n");
 }
```

}